# python tuple to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the data from the database, I ran out.

```
policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
for i in policy_id:
    print i
```

but i want result as:

```
p.policy_id in ('%s','%s','%s') %(i[0],i[1],i[2])
#i[0]=2309
#i[1]=118
#i[2]=94
```

My English is not good, compared to the earlier question did not get what I want, I am a novice, please understand.

Answer (score 1):

You got what you want. You got told that from each of the items you could fethc the 0th "sub-item". So a zeroth approach could be

```
c.execute("foo bar blub where p.policy_id in (%s,%s,%s)", (i[0][0], i[1][0], i[2][0]))
```

An alternative could be to first transform the tuple

```
ii = tuple(x[0] for x in i)
c.execute("foo bar blub where p.policy_id in (%s,%s,%s)", ii)
```

Note that I as well include information about how to properly access the MySQLdb cursor. This is not done via string formatting, but via the `data` parameter of `cursor.execute()` in order to have the data properly escaped.